# Adobe Illustrator CC 2020 Type on a path tool not working properly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I'm having an issue with my Adobe Illustrator CC2020 24.3.

Im attempting to create a type on a path logo, with the one layer of text flipped
so it reads the same way on both sides. I am able to create the path with the eclipse tool,
and I am able to get the type on the path.

However, after that, the tool doesn't work properly. I am not able to see the tool handles/tips where the lines to flip and adjust the type.

I have done an experiment where I was able to create the type on a path on illustrator CC2018 version 23.0.1, on another machine, and then opened it in my illustrator, the opened file sees the tools, but if I copy and paste the type into my document, then the tools disappear again.

Please help

see screenshots
Thank you[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose `View > Show Edges` from the menu.

You can disable highlighting via this menu command and its shortcut. It appears as though the highlighting is merely disabled.

You *may have* inadvertently hit the shortcut - <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

---

Note the object highlighting is *different* and *separate* from the bounding box... which would be why you see the bounding box but no object highlighting in your first image.

Comment: Thanks Scott, My rookie Mistake. You're the brains in this operation! I have another question : Remember Freehand? lol. Yes, back in the day you could paste a shape onto a path and duplicate it too, almost using it as type. Is this still possible with illustrator? Ive cut and pasted paths and im not succeeding.. any input would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Brendan, Although I was certainly working in the heydays of the AI vs FH wars `:)`... I was never a FH user - *always* preferred AI.. so I'm completely unfamiliar with FH. In AI you **can't** paste anything "into" a path. You **can** create a **clipping mask** using *shapes* though. Which is essentially one shape with other objects inside it. The help files for "Clipping Masks" can explain more than I can here.

Comment: @Brendan, you can in InDesign. Check out [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/143872/84899).

Comment: @Brendan I used to be a Freehand user. Yes you could paste vector shapes into text, either text on a path, or just ordinary text - it was called an "inline graphic".  As far as I know, Illustrator never had such a feature. I miss it.